# I am using sass file in react component but compiler give some errors

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, styling

I am using *Sass* file in *react* component but compiler give some errors.

Below is the line of code where compiler gives error:

```
$easeInOut: cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.03, 0.515, 0.955);

$turnDuration: 0.6s

// Animation  

mixin = animate($name, $easing, $duration: 300ms, $delay: 0s, $iteration: 1, $direction: normal, $fill-mode: forwards)
    animation: $name $duration $easing $delay $iteration $direction $fill-mode
```

**Error**

> ./src/styles/flipclock.scss (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-3!./src/styles/flipclock.scss)
>   $easeInOut: cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.03, 0.515, 0.955);
>    ^
>        Media query expression must begin with '('
>        in F:\AMS\client\src\styles\flipclock.scss (line 6, column 1)

[image: error]

Comment: Sometimes the line of code doesn't really get to the core of the issues. The error message itself points to a faulty media-query. ```Media query expression must begin with '('``` Could you check if all the media-queries are written properly without syntax errors?

Comment: @ArnoTenkink, I am new to Sass. Please tell me the syntax for media queries.

Comment: media queries look like `@media screen and (min-width: 320px) { more code goes in here }`

Answer (score 1):

Please run the below command:

> npm install --save-dev webpack

Or

> npm rebuild node-sass

Or

> remove node_modules folder and run npm install

Answer (score 1):

I debugged your SASS file. SASS is pretty sensitieve to input. Maybe you can start with SCSS, it's the same platform only different and easier syntax.

You can validate your SASS here, to get 'other' errors that your complicer doesn't give. https://www.sassmeister.com/

- You mixed tabs and spaces.
- Mixin was wrong, use `@mixin`. The mixin also contained a space so it's wasnt at the root.
- Some other syntax errors solved with the sassmeister website.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans+Mono')

// $easeIn: cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94)
// $easeOut: cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.085, 0.68, 0.53)
$easeInOut: cubic-bezier(0.455, 0.03, 0.515, 0.955)

$turnDuration: 0.6s

// animation mixin
@mixin animate($name, $easing, $duration: 300ms, $delay: 0s, $iteration: 1, $direction: normal, $fill-mode: forwards) 
  animation: $name $duration $easing $delay $iteration $direction $fill-mode

* 
  box-sizing: border-box

body
  margin: 0

#app
  display: flex
  position: relative
  width: 100%
  min-height: 100vh
  justify-content: center
  align-items: center
  background-color: #FBAB7E
  background-image: linear-gradient(62deg, #FBAB7E 0%, #F7CE68 100%)

header
  display: flex
  position: relative

  h1
    font-family: 'Droid Sans Mono', monospace
    font-weight: lighter
    text-transform: uppercase
    letter-spacing: 0.1em
    color: white

$border: whitesmoke
$card: white
$font-family: 'Droid Sans Mono', monospace
$font-size: 2em
$font-width: lighter
$font-color: lighten(black, 20%)

.flipClock
  display: flex
  // justify-content: s
  width: 3 * 100px + 80px

.flipUnitContainer
  display: block
  position: relative
  width: 140px
  height: 120px
  perspective-origin: 50% 50%
  perspective: 300px
  background-color: $card
  border-radius: 3px
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px -10px grey

.upperCard, .lowerCard
  display: flex
  position: relative
  justify-content: center
  width: 100%
  height: 50%
  overflow: hidden
  border: 1px solid $border
  
  span
    font-size: $font-size
    font-family: $font-family
    font-weight: $font-width
    color: $font-color

.upperCard
  align-items: flex-end
  border-bottom: 0.5px solid $border
  border-top-left-radius: 3px
  border-top-right-radius: 3px
  
  span
    transform: translateY(50%)

.lowerCard
  align-items: flex-start
  border-top: 0.5px solid $border
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px
  
  span
    transform: translateY(-50%)

.flipCard
  display: flex
  justify-content: center
  position: absolute
  left: 0
  width: 100%
  height: 50%
  overflow: hidden
  backface-visibility: hidden
  
  span
    font-family: $font-family
    font-size: $font-size
    font-weight: $font-width
    color: $font-color
  
  &.unfold
    top: 50%
    align-items: flex-start
    transform-origin: 50% 0%
    transform: rotateX(180deg) // from 180 to 0
    background-color: $card
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px
    border: 0.5px solid $border
    border-top: 0.5px solid $border
    
    span
      transform: translateY(-50%)
    
  &.fold
    top: 0%
    align-items: flex-end
    transform-origin: 50% 100%
    transform: rotateX(0deg) // from 0 to -180
    background-color: $card
    border-top-left-radius: 3px
    border-top-right-radius: 3px
    border: 0.5px solid $border
    border-bottom: 0.5px solid $border
    
    span
      transform: translateY(50%)  

.fold
  @include animate("fold", $easeInOut, 0.6s) 
  transform-style: preserve-3d

.unfold
  @include animate("unfold", $easeInOut, 0.6s)
  transform-style: preserve-3d

@keyframes fold
  0%
    transform: rotateX(0deg)
  100%
    transform: rotateX(-180deg)

@keyframes unfold
  0%
    transform: rotateX(180deg)
  100%
    transform: rotateX(0deg)
```

Comment: Could you post the whole file instead of just this snippet?

Comment: you can see file on this link 